# Praw: How to get top posts that were created in last 24 hours?

Tags: python, python-3.x, praw

I want to get top posts of a subreddit but I only get top posts of all time. How to filter the search results so it only looks for today posts?

My code:

```
top_memes = subreddit.top(limit=5)

for submission in top_memes:
    print(submission.title)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `time_filter` parameter for `.top()` accepts one of the following values: *all, day, hour, month, week, year*.

```
top_memes = subreddit.top("day", limit=5)
```

https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/subreddit.html#praw.models.Subreddit.top

Answer (score 5):

When PRAW 8 rolls out, you MUST specify `time_filter'.

```
top_memes = subreddit.top(time_filter="day", limit=5)
```

https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/subreddit.html#praw.models.Subreddit.top

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).